# Error while extending Web application in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to extend my sharepoint 2013 web application to Extranet zone

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://myServer-01:1111/  | New-SPWebApplicationExtension -Name "ExtendTemp" -SecureSocketsLayer -Zone "Extranet" -URL "https://extranet.1111.com"
```

It takes a very long time and I get this error message:

> New-SPWebApplicationExtension : The web configuration file,
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\1111\web.config, does not have
>   element "authentication" or it is invalid.

But when I check in Central admin, I am able to see the extended web app.

The actual problem I am facing is [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32467.sharepoint-2013-sorry-were-having-trouble-reaching-the-server.aspx). In short, my properly working web app is corrupted now for some unknown reasons(There wasn't any patch update either). The solution given in the mentioned page is to extend the and remove the extension.

Though I am able to see the extended site in the central admin, the main issue is not resolved yet (Even after reboot).

So I am stuck in the first step only(Extension of web app). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by comparing the web.config files of a working web application and the non-working web app.

The following lines were missing under :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/_login/default.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

I added the above code and did an IIS Reset. And the issue got resolved.